# Applying an MST to multiple MSIs

Tags: windows-installer, transform

Is it possible to apply an MST to multiple MSIs?

If I have a suite of products that I want to deliver, what I would like to be able to do is (the way I understand mst and msi) to:

- Product.msi
- General.mst
- Configuration.mst

The Product.msi is the product from the vendor.

The General.mst, is a transform that creates, for example, generic fields in the registry to keep track of the software installed by other packaging tools

Configuration.mst is a transform that configures the product in a certain way.

Is it possible to apply the General.mst to all of the other products that I choose to deliver/install? That way I can maintain the General.mst file separately, and not recreate it for each product.

Is this even an optimal approach?

Answer (score 0):

An MST can be created for and applied to multiple MSIs but there is some schema validation that applies that might get in your way.

I assume you are working in an enterprise IT environment ( SCCM et al ).  What happens when you have an installer that isn't an MSI?

Personally I haven't attempted to do what you are doing.  I've always just used inventory data for reporting.

Comment: If an installer is not an msi, I just repackage it as an msi.

Comment: I know from experience that's not 100% true.

Comment: Which part are you referring to?